# iterate through fb:random

Tags: php, mysql, iteration, facebook

does anyone know how i would fill data from mysql database in fb:random and iterate through it, to pick a random quote?

fb:random

```
$facebook->api_client->fbml_setRefHandle('quotes',
'<fb:random>
<fb:random-option>Quote 1</fb:random-option>
<fb:random-option>Quote 2</fb:random-option>
</fb:random>');
```

mysql data:

```
$rowcount = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
$rand = rand(0,$rowcount-1);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT cQuotes, vAuthor, cArabic, vReference FROM thquotes LIMIT $rand, 1", $conn)
  or die ('Error: '.mysql_error());


$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
if ( !$row ) {
  echo "Empty";
}
else{

$fb_box = "<p>" . h($row['cArabic']) . "</p>";
$fb_box .= "<p>" . h($row['cQuotes']) . "</p>";
$fb_box .= "<p>" . h($row['vAuthor']) . "</p>";
$fb_box .= "<p>" . h($row['vReference']) . "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, what I do when I want to pick up a random quote or other piece of data is I select all of the `id`s in the database, feed them into an array, and then choose at random from the array.  Then use the `id` to pick out the one you want.

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `quotes`;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

$id = rand(1, $count);

$sql = "SELECT `text`,`author` FROM `quotes` WHERE `id`='$id' LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$quote = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: i'm already doing that. but i would like to know how would i do this using the fb:random tag?